# Epplus - how to freeze the top row of a worksheet

Tags: freeze, epplus

Using EPPlus, freezing pane by using `ws.View.FreezePanes(2, 1)` will freeze the top row of the current displayed rows. When opening the file using excel programmatically how to make sure that it will be the first line of the spreadsheet that will be frozen?